# Combining multiple callbacks in javascript

Tags: javascript, async-await, asynccallback

In my call back response of `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` gets undefined or `True`. When `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` receives a message it communicates to a native application and retrieves a response. I want to return that response to the `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` response. I tried learning about combing two callbacks, but didn't have any luck over there.

```
async processMsg(response, param2) {}

async function A1(msg, sender) {
      await chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage(hostName, mesg,async function(response) {
            var resp = await processMsg(response, param2);
            return resp;
        });

  return true;
}


chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
   A1(msg, sender).then(sendResponse);
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should to return the promise in A1 function, like this:

```js
async processMsg(response, param2) {
    return "not null"
}

async function A1(msg, sender) {
    return await chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage(hostName, mesg,async function(response) {
        return processMsg(response, param2);
    });
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
    A1(msg, sender).then(sendResponse);
    return true; //I don't think you need to return anything here
});
```

Comment: Receiving `null` in the `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` response.

Comment: Thatsprobably because processMsg was empy, try now

Comment: I am returning content from processMsg. It still gives null.